# Is there a way to customise keyboard shortcuts for a Java executable?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, java

Is there a way to customise keyboard shortcuts for a Java executable? I cannot add it in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts as it's an executable and does not end in .app.

It's part of the JRE ([Java SE Runtime Environment](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)) bundle in `Contents/Home/bin/java`.

Comment: Well once you build the app won't the executable be placed in a .app package?

Comment: @JBis No, the app is started with a launcher (which is the .app package).